# Template filters do not work inside include

Tags: python, django

I am trying to use the build in template tag filter `default_if_none`. However it appears not to work when I include it in an `{% include %}` tag, e.g.

```
{% include 'foobar.html' with myfield=myfield %}
```

Where foobar.html is:

```
{{ myfield | default_if_none: '' }}
```

When I place the html inside the parent document it works as expected. Does this have something to do with the include tag? How can I fix this?

Comment: No, normally it should work. What exactly does it produce here? `None`?

Comment: For debugging, print the myfield and then use `{{ myfield | default_if_none: '----- ' }}` I think the `myfield` is not passed correctly to the include.

Comment: Turns out Gorjux was right. Thanks for the tip.